# Laptop says WIFI is Hard Blocked Atheros AR9565

Tags: debian, wifi, hardware

I have a problem with the wifi.

I need to plug to power to activate it.

- LAPTOP ACER ES1-522-223C
- Debian 8.7
- firmware-atheros V 0.43 ath9k installed

  lspci --> 02:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)

I have to plug the power to make it change and I can unplug the power after it starts. Even when laptop goes suspend or any similar mode I need to plug the power to get wifi working again.

When rfkill list after pluging in the power I get the following:

```
sudo rfkill list 
[...] 
1: phy0: Wireless LAN 
    Soft blocked: no 
    Hard blocked: no 
[...]
```

I've tried everything I have read and I am beginning to suspect that it could be a BIOS problem or something related to the Fn+F3 key. The idea about the Fn+F3 is not really clear because the other combinations of Fn+FX are working.

Comment: Hello and welcome. I give you an upvote for your question and answer. But keep in mind, that it's common practice not to answer your own question. Better edit your original post and insert your solution there, via **Update:** ...

Comment: Thank you, i understand. You're right. I did it because this question was holded at askubuntu because i use Debian. As i had to move the question i also broguht my own answer.

Answer (score 2):

**[SOLUTION]**

Really easy. It works fine even though the Fn+F3 keys have no effect.

I added the blacklist-acer-wmi.conf file to the modprobe.d directory and the blacklist option set to acer_wmi. after that reboot.

Run this command.

`echo "blacklist acer_wmi" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-acer-wmi.conf`